# (AngularJS + Bootstrap) Resource reservation component

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am writing a simple AngularJS/Bootstrap/Spring-MVC CRUD application that allows me to manage 3 types of objects: *person*, *room* and *reservation*. *Reservation* type has a relation to both room and person object both in DB and Java backend.

The simple parts have been made and now I need to know what would be the best approach for creating a graphical calendar-style view showing the reservations.

I can imagine it either as a new AngularJS directive (or maybe just simple ng-repeat with extended controller) or a jQuery script module.
The question though is - **what is better performance-wise?**

- Should I try to use the HTML5 to draw a canvas on it, or can I simply add 50-150 divs on one page and use those as representations 
  of my entities in the calendar?
- Won't it kill the browser if I have this many divs each floating atop other? Also each of them needs to have listeners and other dynamic events attached to them so pretty heavy stuff, no?

Comment: Are you looking to have it work on mobile? On tablet? Is it purely for personal use or will it be for public use? 150 divs shouldn't be a problem for most environments, and event listeners can be simplified by adding a single event delegation handler instead of one listener per div.

Comment: Would [this Angular UI calendar widget](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/) save you from reinventing the wheel and show you that it is possible and performant?

Comment: @GregL I've seen this widget before and unfortunately this is not the functionality I am looking for.. I need to have a view where each resource will have a separate line/row. Additionally, I need to have more than one month in view - rather 90 days. In fact I am thinking of using a **table** with ~90 columns and overlaying my divs over them.
ad1. This is for personal use, and it will be user on PC/Laptops. However, since I am doing it in Bootstrap I am silently hoping it will run acceptably on smartphones too..

Comment: Tables are not usually a good choice if you want it to be responsive. Though if the desired effect is just a shrunk down version of the table, then maybe it will work. So are you after kind of like a Gantt chart type of look? Maybe using [D3.js](http://d3js.org/) to render it in SVG would be a good solution, then. Check out the examples to see what it can do.

Comment: Yes, Gantt layout is exactly what I am looking for!
As for D3.js - indeed looks very interesting and appropriate, but it also seems it will require a great deal of JS writing for integration with my simple project. I may give it a shot somewhere in the future as an upgrade to the div-soup I am looking at now