# How to append an element with angular-ui popover

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a function that appends divs to each cell in a table. You can imagine it as a table with a div in each cell. I do this by means of:

```
angular.element(document.getElementById()).append("<div>a</div>")
```

This works absolutely fine.
However, I need this appended div to have a popover on it. This doesn't work:

```
em.append("<div popover='text' popover-trigger='mouseenter'>a</div>")
```

It appears to me that the popover directive is only attached to items on page-render. Any new items added after are not being tracked by the directive. How to fix it?

PS: if I add the same div but directly in the html template the popover works like a charm.

Comment: Just Curious, After appending html did you recompile the dom?

Comment: This is very jQuery-ish vs. AngularJS.  If you're doing this in a controller, don't (https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.5/docs/guide/controller).  DOM manipulation should happen in a directive.  Best if you give a working/non-working sample, then you'll get better answers. In general though, you'll have to compile before appending by calling the $compile service.

Comment: I was missing the compile part as you suspected. Added that and it works fine now. @jme11 - I absolutely agree with you. And I hate to use plain jQ in AngularJS but Angular simply does not have the tools I need for my purpose. Please see here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30046763
I need a grid to which I later add elements - the grid has hundreds of cells. To do it the Angular way I'd have to keep a reference to each cell in app memory. With my solution I reference to DOM objects by their ID. Let me know if you got any better idea - I sure could use one!

Comment: Actually, based on that question and your comment above, seems like you really don't understand yet how Angular works.  That's not meant as an insult, in fact, it reminds me that when I was new to AngularJS, I might have thought that a jQuery-style approach was the only way too.  What you see as a very complex and resource intensive application seems to be trivial in AngularJS with two custom directives and ng-repeat. Adding/removing entries would just be a matter of updating the scope. Maybe post to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ to get some advice on your approach.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by 2 custom directives and ng-repeat? Please provide more details - your comment does not bring any value apart from being derogative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) service for this to work. If you do it like this, it should work:

```
em.append($compile("<div popover='text' popover-trigger='mouseenter'>a</div>")($scope));
```

Comment: This is the answer. However, do I need to run this after each append? I am adding tons of divs in a loop. Can I call compile after all of them once? Also, what does compile do here??

Comment: I think you can also compile the whole $element in your directive after you're done manipulating your DOM. I'm not really sure if this works, but just try it out. Read [here](http://www.benlesh.com/2013/08/angular-compile-how-it-works-how-to-use.html) about what `$compile` does.

Comment: The same holds true for adding a tooltip.